# How can I have 2 sentinels in an iterator?

Tags: python, iterator

I am using the following code snippet to read all the content of a file between 2 lines delimited by start_string and stop_string

```
with open(file_name) as file:
    start_token = next(l for l in file if l.strip()==start_string) # Used to read until the start token
    result = [line for line in iter(lambda x=file: next(x).strip(), stop_string) if line]

return `result`
```

My problem is that I have discovered that some times the stop_string can have 2 different values, so I want to specify them to the sentinel.

Something like

```py
result = [line for line in iter(lambda x=file: next(x).strip(), stop_string or stop_string_2") if line]
```

The idea is that the sentinel is `stop_strin`g or s`top_string_2`

The above code is obviously incorrect, but how can I accomplish it?

How can I have multiple sentinels in an iter?

Comment: Have you tried using regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a particularly good approach. I can suggest an alternative:

```
stop_strings = {stop_string, stop_string2}
with open(file_name) as file:
    iterator = iter(file)
    for line in iterator:
        if line.strip() == start_string:
            break

    result = []
    for line in iterator:
        result.append(line.strip())
        if line.strip() in stop_strings:
            break
```

Or probably better:

```
stop_strings = {stop_string, stop_string2}
with open(file_name) as file:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in file]

start = lines.index(start_string)
stop = next(i for i in range(start, len(lines)) if lines[i] in stop_strings)
result = lines[start+1:stop]
```

If you insist on a functional style, there is:

```
import itertools as it

stop_strings = {stop_string, stop_string2}
with open(file_name) as file:
    after_start = it.islice(it.dropwhile(lambda s: s.strip() != start_string, file),
                            1, None)
    before_end = it.takewhile(lambda s: s.strip() not in stop_strings, after_start)
    result = list(before_end)
```

Comment: Really good input.

Just one question, in the second approach, why you reversed the list of lines?

Are you assuming that the end string is closer to the end of the file that to the start of the file? Because that is not the case, and it is probably closer to the start of the file than to the end.

Comment: @GonzaloMurillo I changed it.

Comment: OK, I settled with the first approach, as it is the clearer for my Python level right now. Just one correction. This line "iterator = file.iter()", must be "iterator = iter(file)

Apart from that, your response was awesome and complete. Thanks!

Comment: @GonzaloMurillo Right, too much Rust recently ^^